# Controller Problem when using MVC in Object Orientated PHP

Tags: php, model-view-controller, search, get

I am currently programming a book store using MVC in Object Orientated PHP and I am having a hard time working out how the controller should work when dealing with requests, especially when dealing with forms.

For example, I have a search form that is shown when the user visits "index.php?action=search" however I am unsure how i should deal with the search string from the form as i cannot send the "$_GET['action'] = search" again so that "index.php?action?search=searchstring" is sent to the browser so that the search results are shown without using a hidden field to send the search action which is of course very unsecure!!

I feel like this is all too much effort for what its worth and proceedural seems a better way of attempting this so far!! Unless you can convince me otherwise!!

Thanks

Dan.

Comment: http://oreilly.com/pub/a/php/archive/mvc-intro.html?page=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should understand that The MVC Patter in PHP Is usually set out like so:

You have 2 key variables that are:

- class
- method

And they always default to:

- class = index
- method = index

So when the parameter `class` is passed into the URI then it overrides the default so using `index.php?class=view` the above becomes:

- class = view
- method = index

There for you run the class view.php and initialize the view class into an object, and execute the method like so:

```
class View/*_Controller extends Controller*/
{
     public function index(){}
}
```

Any other variables passed would be available via the GET Request, or POST.

You should also note that this is usually handled via the URI within the URL Syntax, so the following `index.php?action=view&method=download` becomes `/view/download/`

Anything within the URI, after the class/method would be sent to the method, example below.

```
/view/download/id/browser
```

This will execute the following method and pass in the values for the variables in context.

```
class View/*_Controller extends Controller*/
{
     public function download($id,$direction)
     {
     }
}
```

Now I know that this is not specific to your question but i think your going the wrong way about things and this should help you start laying your framework out into a manageable structure.

---

## Update

The Controller initialized by the GET/POST using a router, a router is a class that detects the class / method from the URI and then finds the correct controller and executes it along with its method.

An example of a router is like so:

```
class Router
{
    //Params
    public $route;

    public static function CreateRoute($route = false)
    {
        return new Router($route);
    }

    public function __construct($route = false)
    {
         if($route !== false)
         {
              $this->route = $route;
         }else
         {
             $this->route = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
         }

         /*
             * The route would be parsed so that the following are matched
             * {/class}{/method}{/param1}{/param1}
             * /view/download/12/direct | as example
         */
    }


    public function run()
    {
        /*
            * Here you would do the following:
            * Validate the class to make sure no one is triggering an LFI
            * Make sure the class file exists within the directory
            * Include the class file and create an instance of it
            * Execute the method  sending in the params.
        */
    }
}
```

Usage like so:

```
$Route = Router::CreateRoute(); //AutoDetect
$Route->run();
```

Take a look at the following image, may help you understand.
[image: Codeigniter Application Flow Chart]

Comment: Thanks, makes a bit more sense. I vaguely remember how ruby on rails worked which i guess is the same concept in a different language. Although, i still dont understand fully how the controller deals with $_POST and $_GET requests, is this all done using mod_rewrite ??

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your case you should actually redirect with an extra parameter. Use `index.php?action=search&q=searchstring` for example. That would retain the ability to invoke the right "controller" solely based on the action param.

As for the "MVC" part you are right. It's [not overly applicable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549857/simple-php-mvc-framework/1549970#1549970) to web apps. But you could read up on Model-View-Presenter, which better resembles what everyone is doing anyway.

Comment: What do you mean by redirect?? I can't add that to the action parameter within the html form as it won't let me and I don't see any other way of doing it...

Comment: @DanielWest: Well use a hidden form field. I don't see the problem there, neither what gave you the impression this is "very unsecure".

Comment: I was told it was insecure due to it being vulnerable to javacript injection and also people saving the page and tampering with it...

Comment: @DanielWest: That was wrong advise. All $_GET parameters can be tampered with, as well as all $_POST parameters. Users can either modify the URL or form fields, makes no difference. What your application should do is only honor allowed values. Use some processing scheme like `if ($_GET["action"]=="search")` or a simple call-map for objects/functions - just like the FrontController logic @Robert describes. To prevent Javascript injection ("XSS") simply escape all user input using `htmlspecialchars(...,"utf-8")` should you ever output it again.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with `index.php?action=search&q=WHATEVER`, accomplished with this HTML:

```
<form method="GET" action="index.php">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="search" />
Search: <input type="text" name="q" />
<!-- ... -->
```

This is approximately how search engines do it, except that they use URL rewriting to make the URLs prettier. For example, a Bing search for "test" is http://www.bing.com/search?q=test.

MVC may seem like a hassle when you are first learning it, but it really is a productive and convenient pattern for web development that is far superior to procedural-style "anything goes" web development.

Comment: Thanks, I thought this was one way of doing it although I was told it was insecure and not the best way to go about it...

Comment: @DanielWest: One thing that you do need to guard against is if the user types junk into the URL for the `action` parameter value. Perhaps that is what that person was referring to by "insecure". Even then, it's a stretch as most MVC frameworks automatically provide some form of protection.